# Sending array as message in omnet++

Tags: c++, arrays, message, omnet++

I am totally a beginner at OMNeT++. I want to set an array as a message and send it through my modules. These arrays are weight and bias in a neural network. And they'll update in every module. I already wrote code for this in c++ by including `<array>` and using it,  but I don't know how can I use `<array>` and define my message in the .msg file in OMNeT++.
Please help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using `<array>` is not necessary. To declare arrays of 10 elements in the message one should write something like:

```
message MyMessage {
   double weights[10];
   double bias[10];
}
```

Moreover, if you don't know the size of array in advance, you may declare variable size array:

```
message MyMessage {
   double weights[];
   double bias[];
}
```

Dealing with arrays in message definition is described in [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:msg-defs:fixed-size-arrays).